# Disable ActionMode starting depends on ListView item type

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionmode

I have ListView which contains data of 2 types. I want to start action mode only if 1 type was long pressed.

This is how i enable action mode.

```
 listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
 listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(multiChoiceModeListener);
```

How to disable action mode for the second view type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
public class DeviceExclListView extends ListView{

private ActionMode mAm;
private boolean mActionModeStarted;

public DeviceExclListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public DeviceExclListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public DeviceExclListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public ActionMode startActionMode(Callback callback) {
    return mAm = super.startActionMode(callback);
}

@Override
public boolean performItemClick(View view, int position, long id) {

    Object item = getItemAtPosition(position);
    if(item instanceof DeviceItem && mActionModeStarted){
        return true;
    }else{
        return super.performItemClick(view, position, id);
    }

}

@Override
public void setItemChecked(int position, boolean value) {
    Object item = getItemAtPosition(position);
    if(item instanceof DeviceItem){
        mAm.finish();
    }else{
        super.setItemChecked(position, value);
    }
}

public boolean isActionModeStarted() {
    return mActionModeStarted;
}

public void setActionModeStarted(boolean mActionModeStarted) {
    this.mActionModeStarted = mActionModeStarted;
}


}
```

setActionModeStarted is setted by MultiChoiceModeListenerCallback. So when I long press DeviceItem actionmode close instantly and it doesn't checkable during action mode.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me (for the `AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener` callback):

```
@Override
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                      long id, boolean checked)
{
    Item item = mAdapter.getItem(position);
    if (!item.checkable && checked) {
        // Uncheck the item
        mListView.setItemChecked(position, false);
        return;
    }

    // the rest of the usual logic
    // ...
}
```

Basically, if an item that shouldn't be checked is checked, we uncheck it.